# How to display github step summary on GitHub Actions with windows-latest

Tags: windows, github-actions

I am unable to generate a [summary](https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/) for github actions on windows. The following script encapsulates the script.

Using the following script:

```yaml
name: Testing windows summaries

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    types: [synchronize, opened, reopened, ready_for_review]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: "windows-latest"
    steps:
    - name: Adding markdown
      run: |
       echo '### Hello world! ' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
       cat $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

Produces the following error:

```bash
Get-Content: D:\a\_temp\e90ee597-2b32-4d33-ba5c-0ae6be835be0.ps1:7
Line |
   7 |  cat $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So the problem seems that the variable `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` never gets a value.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for some time I found the solution to the problem. On windows the [default shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) does not seem to work well with the `>>` operator. The solution is to change the script above for:

```yaml
name: Testing windows summaries

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    types: [synchronize, opened, reopened, ready_for_review]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: "windows-latest"
    steps:
    - name: Adding markdown
      run: |
        echo '### Hello world! ' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
        cat $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY 
      shell: bash
```

Where we have added a explicit shell instruction at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` is an environment variable. In Bash these are accessed via prefixing `$`. In PowerShell these are accessed via prefixing `$env:`. So your original example would work by changing it to

```
echo '### Hello world! ' >> $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

or even simpler

```
'### Hello world! ' >> $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

---

As for the specific error you were getting, `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` in PowerShell is looking for a variable with that name (rather than an environment variable). Because you don't have a variable by that name, the value is null and the redirection operator (`>>`) doesn't know where to send the output.